# Issues with function output using if/else if

Tags: c++

I am (new to c++) trying to create a power function manually and came across the issue where if the power inputted is negative, the result is always being printed out as 0. I suspect that one of the variables might not be declared properly, can you help please

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int power;
float result = 1, base;

int firs();
void pow(int base, int power);

int main()
{
    firs();
    pow(base, power);

    return 0;
}

int firs()
{
    cout << "Enter a base input: ";
    cin >> base;

    cout << "Enter a power input: ";
    cin >> power;

    return base, power;
}

void pow(int base, int power)
{
    cout << "With a given base of " << base << " and a given power of " << power << endl;

    if (power > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
        {
            result = result*base;
        }

    cout << "The final answer is: " << result;

    }
    else if (power < 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > power; i--)
        {
            result = result*(1/base);
        }

    cout << "The final answer is: " << result;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The final answer is: " << 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tony Yes, comma operator (`,`) executes all statements from left to right, and returns the rightmost one. So `return base, power;` is exactly the same as `return power;`

Comment: Don't know what sense does that make...

Comment: In C/C++ you can only return one value from a function. Or give back a struct or change values by references

Comment: @Tony [more info here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: It takes me awhile to see that `base` definition in `pow` function is shadowing `base` definition at global scope. The former is `int` and the later is `float`

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the following code section:

```
    else if (power < 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > power; i--)
        {
            result = result*(1/base);
        }
    }
```

When `(1/base)` is calculated, because both `1` and `base` are `int`, the result will also be casted into `int`, which is `0` (if `base` is greater than `1`). You can avoid this by either defining `base` as `float`, using `1.0` instead of `1`, or using [explicit type casting](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/):

```
    else if (power < 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > power; i--)
        {
            result = result*(1/(float) base);
        }
    }
```

Also, [`return base, power` only returns `power`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comna-in-c-and-c/).

Comment: Ah, just as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
        result = result*(1/base);
```

to

```
        result = result*(1.0/base);
```

And you will get the correct result.